# MVC 5 - why am I loosing session variables with session mode=StateServer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, variables, asp.net-mvc-5

I have and ASP.NET MVC 5 application where I use the ASP.NET Session to store some objects. By default the session mode was **InProc** and very soon I noticed that these objects started to intermittently disappear from the session. Apparently something was restarting the app_pool so the whole session was getting cleared. I switched the session mode to **StateServer** (out of process - ASP.NET State Service) thinking that this will solve my problem completely. What really happened was the objects that I put into the session still disappear, but only less frequently. Apparently StateServer session mode is resistant to app_pool restart, but not resistant to some other things.

So my question is: What could be these other things? What can be causing the ASP.NET Session to clear when the mode is **StateServer** (stored outside of IIS)?

Comment: Is the stateserver service started and did you configured it well?

Comment: What is the frequency that the session is cleared and what is the session timeout?

Comment: - The state service is started and configured properly because the site is working fine for the most part. Every 2-3 days I find in my error logs a new occurrence of  "session variable is null". The session timeout is set to 120